# Как задать двойное условие switch

Tags: swift3, switch

Вот у меня есть `enum` который я проверяю в `switch`

```
enum Action {
    case Walk(meters : Int)
    case Run(meters : Int, speed : Int)
    case Stop
    case Turn(direction : Direction)

    enum Direction {
        case Left
        case Right
    }
}

func checkAction (action : Action) {
    switch action {
    case Action.Run(let meters, let a) where meters < 32:
        print("Run \(a)", terminator : "")
    default: break
    }
}
```

Вот так работает, но если задаю два условия то не работает

```
case Action.Run(let meters, let a) where meters < 32, a < 22:
    print("Run \(a)", terminator : "")
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: мне кажется, для начала нужно код писать, так, чтобы было понятно где, что и как, а не тратить уйму времени на распределение блоков кода, а уж потом только на решение. Не хотел обидеть, если что)

Comment: @ikerya ниче не понял из вашего не внятного комментария... Как по мне тут нечего объяснять есть `enum` и есть функция которая его принимает. В функции `switch` который в зависимости от значения выполняет действия. Так вот мой вопрос в том как в `switch case` задать два условия `where` подобно тому как описано в вопросе. Читайте внимательнее вопрос если хотели быть полезным. Не хотел обидеть, если что)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считайте что where равен if. Правильная запись:

```
case Action.Run(let meters, let a) where meters < 32 && a < 22:
    print("Run \(a)", terminator : "")
```